# Linux - Erro ao instalar Guest additions do Virtual Box no Ubuntu 16.04 LTS em Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

Acabei de instalar a nova versão do Ubuntu - 16.04 LTS numa máquina virtual - Virtual Box. O meu sistema operacional é o Windows 7, 64bits, Lenovo.
Tentei instalar o Guest additions através do instalador do Menu: Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image ... .
Segui os passos e essa foi a mensagen que recebei no terminal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre esse erro mas sem sucesso.
Alguem sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Bem, quem votou menos, deveria explicar pq ou dar a resposta.

Comment: A pergunta não faz parte do escopo do site. Apesar disso não justificar os downvotes, mas sim o fechamento dela.

Comment: Esse comando pode ajudar voce: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms

Answer (score 2):

Embora pareça ser uma pergunta fora do tópico, a resposta talvez seja útil pois mesmo no super user, não a encontramos.

Basta rodar essa linha de código:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms //Yes para todas opções
```

Uma nota importante. 
A versão 16.04.1 do Ubuntu parece não precisar de guest additions para maximizar a tela do Linux. O que faz essa linha de código acima, parecer desnecessária.

Porém se houver interesse ou necessidade em fazer compartilhamento de diretórios entre o windows host e o linux guest,  esse código é indispensável.

Para saber os detlhes soble compartilhamento após esse código, veja essa fonte: https://gist.github.com/igoralves1/eda8e0f2692e04d633effa833ae36e32

3  - Install virtualbox-guest
4  - Sharing Folder